# Comparing/finding the difference between two text files using findstr

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, findstr

I have a requirement to compare two text files and to find out the difference between them. Basically I have an input file (input.txt) which will be processed by a batch job and my batch will log the output (successful.txt) where the job has successfully ran.

In simple words, I need to find out the difference between input.txt and successful.txt (input.txt-successful.txt) and I was thinking to use findstr. It seems to be fine, BUT I don't understand one part of it. It always includes the last line of my input.txt in the output. You could see that in the example below. Please note that there is no leading space or line break after the last line of my input.txt.

In below example, you could see the line `server1,db1` is present on both the files, but still listed in the output. (It is always the last line of input.txt)

```
D:\Scripts\dummy>type input.txt
server2,db2
server3,db3
server10,db10
server4,db4
server1,db11
server10,schema11
host1,sch2
host11,sql2
host11,sql3
server1,db1
D:\Scripts\dummy>type successful.txt
server1,db1
server2,db2
server3,db3
server4,db4
server10,db10
host1,sch2
host11,sql2
host11,sql3
D:\Scripts\dummy>findstr /vixg:successful.txt input.txt
server1,db11
server10,schema11
server1,db1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers,
G

Comment: Put a CR at the end of input.txt. As explained by [dbenham here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman/8844873#8844873)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your results by removing the newline after the last line of `input.txt`, so solution 1 would be to add a newline to the end of `input.txt`. Since you appear to say that `input.txt` has no terminal newline, then adding one would cure the problem; findstr is acting as expected because it acts on newline-terminated lines.

Solution 2 would be

```
type input.txt|findstr /vixg:successful.txt
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know this- `findstr is acting as expected because it acts on newline-terminated lines.` Thanks for your alternate solution as well!